# Почему программа выводит не тот результат, который я ожидаю?

Tags: java

Я изучаю Java второй день и решил сделать суперпростой калькулятор. *Запустите программу, укажите первое число **(я ввожу 50)**, которое будет больше второго **(я ввожу 40)** и выберите действие вычитания.*

Результат работы программы: **Ответ 10, ответ 1**.

Почему пишет **Ответ 1**? И как это убрать?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Перше число:");
        int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Друге число:");
        int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
        int num3;
        System.out.print("Вибери дію:");
        String role = scanner.nextLine();
        role = scanner.nextLine();
        switch (role) {
            case "+":
                num3 = num1 + num2;
                System.out.print("Відповідь " + num3);
            break;
            case "*":
                num3 = num1 * num2;
                System.out.print("Відповідь " + num3);
            break;
            case "-":
                if (num1 > num2) {
                    num3 = num1 - num2;
                    System.out.print("Відповідь" + num3);
                }
                else if (num1 < num2) {
                    num3 = num2 - num1;
                    System.out.print("Відповідь -"+ num3);
            break;
                }
            case "/":
                if (num2 == 0)
                  System.out.print("На ноль ділити не можна!");
            else {
                num3 = num1 / num2;
                System.out.print("Відповідь " + num3);
            break;
        }


    }}}
```

Comment: Потому что у вас break зачем-то запхнут внутрь else if, наверное?

Comment: И ещё один break зачем-то запхнут в else

Comment: Если заберу break то ответ 1 перестанеть выдавать?

Comment: Надо не заберать, а ставить его в точности там, где вы хотите его выполнить

Comment: Я очень чайник в этом, помогите пожалуйста. Куда в моем случае надо его поставить чтобы исправить проблему? Знаю, может тупой вопрос, но хочу понимать что и зачем я делаю, спасибо заранее

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы break выполнялся всегда, то значит после той фигурной скобки, которая закрывает блок else if

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, можете объяснить почему именно в этом месте? и что делает break, а то я не очень понимаю.  Как бы знаю примерно но объяснить сложно

Comment: Читайте в учебниках про switch-case, там обязательно упоминается break

Answer (score 2):

Из-за неправильно расположенного `break` в `case "-"` код выполняет **два** действия вместо одного -- он "проваливается" в следующую операцию деления, поэтому и получается `num1 / num2: 50 / 40 => 1`.

Следует вынести `break` за пределы условных операторов и/или воспользоваться тернарным оператором вместо `if/else`:

```java
Integer num3 = null;
switch (role) {
    case "+":
        num3 = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case "*":
        num3 = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case "-":
        num3 = num1 > num2 ? num1 - num2 : num2 - num1;
        break;
    case "/":
        if (num2 != 0) {
            num3 = num1 / num2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("На ноль делить нельзя!");
        }
        break;
}
if (num3 != null) {
    System.out.println("Ответ: " + num3);
}
```

Также можно воспользоваться более короткой записью `switch-expression`, существующей в полной мере в Java 14 и выше; в такой форме записи оператор `break` не требуется:

```java
Integer num3 = switch (role) {
    case "+" -> num1 + num2;
    case "*" -> num1 * num2;
    case "-" -> num1 > num2 ? num1 - num2 : num2 - num1;
    case "/" -> num2 != 0 ? num1 / num2 : null;
    default -> null;
}
if (num3 != null) {
    System.out.println("Ответ: " + num3);
} else {
    System.out.println("Ошибка ввода!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
` case "-":
            if (num1 > num2) {
                num3 = num1 - num2;
                System.out.print("Відповідь" + num3);
            }else if (num1 < num2) {
                num3 = num2 - num1;
                System.out.print("Відповідь -"+ num3);
            }
            break;`
```

Для решений данной задачи требовалось вынести breack за пределы if/else